# How to handle the google adds Window which display over the page

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, web-testing

[image][image][image: Add Pop Up coming when run the test suite and other operations where failed I tried to click directly on close button with x-path but it not work]
Add Pop Up coming when run the test suite and other operations where failed I tried to click directly on close button with x-path but it not work

Comment: please share your code here to make it easier to solve.

Comment: could share also link for a page under testing or share HTML of this web element?

Comment: Hey Alex I uploaded My code and HTML code.

Comment: The add is within iframe so i tried with iframe but it not working